# HTML CSS image in second column of table not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to create a table which has a list on the first column and an image in the second column. However when I put the image in the second column it moves the list of the first column down. Here is what happens:

[image: image moves list down]

As you can see the image moves the list down. How could I get it so it looks like this:

[image]

This is the code for the table.

```
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li>F1</li>
        <li>ALMS</li>
        <li>Le Mans 24 Hour</li>
        <li>WTCCBritish GT</li>
        <li>BTCC</li>
        <li>Toca support races</li>
     </ul>
   </td>
   <td>
     <a href="http://www.motorground.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/track-day-0732.jpg"><img src="http://www.motorground.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/track-day-0732-300x200.jpg" alt="PrivateTuitionimg073" width="300" height="200" class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-23" /></a>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: #1. Don't use a table for layout (though that's not causing your issue). #2 A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would help.

Comment: Use CSS for layout. HTML for content.

Comment: You should create a **jsFiddle** for this question. Add the stylesheets also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add to your img style:
    float: right
And position it at the bottom of te list in same cell.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you have to set the vertical alignment for the table cell.

Just see this content. This should answer your question ;)

http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html